# How do you run Smokeping on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I've recently switched my Apache web server to Nginx and everything is working great.

The only thing I can't get running, which worked on Apache, is Smokeping (http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/).

Afaik Smokeping is run by a single .cgi script and Nginx can't run those.

Does anyone know how to get Smokeping running on Nginx? Maybe there is a way to convert/run Smokeping as FastCGI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say about making Smokeping use FastCGI, but if that doesn't work out then Nginx can talk CGI via FastCGI: http://wiki.nginx.org/Fcgiwrap

Comment: Yep, an fcgi2cgi wrapper would work fine; there are perl and c versions out there.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it another way which also works well. http://wiki.nginx.org/ThttpdCGI Smokeping running in the minimal thttpd server and proxy from Nginx.